# How to change app Icon without opening the app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have seen that the iPhone Calender app changing its icon daily to have the day number in the month 1,2,3,...,29,30 , How i can make my app change the icon like this ?

Comment: Don't think it's possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the icon isn't possible on iOS, except by submitting an update and including a new icon in your app bundle.

Comment: so how apple implements the calender app to do that ?

Comment: @OmarFreewan Apple is allowed to do anything. 3rd party apps can only do what Apple lets us do through the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple: NSApplication has a method that allows to change the icon image: setApplicationIconImage: .

Comment: That's not relevant in iOS apps

Comment: He is working with iPhone. You cannot change the app icon dynamically, from what I know.